# Serializing a priority queue with custom items in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, serialization, php-5.3, priority-queue

I'm implementing a customized priority queue based on PHP's SPLPriorityQueue in a Zend Application. It contains custom objects, PriorityQueueItens, instead of pure values aside the priority value. When storing the queue in APC (or memcache) I have to make sure the queue and its items are serializable, so I've set them to implement the Serializable interface [using code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/SplPriorityQueue.php) from the upcoming Zend Framework 2.

```
public function serialize()
{
    $data = array();
    while ($this->valid()) {
        $data[] = $this->current();
        $this->next();
    }
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $this->insert($item['data'], $item['priority']);
    }
    return serialize($data);
}

public function unserialize($data)
{
    foreach (unserialize($data) as $item) {
        $this->insert($item['data'], $item['priority']);
    }
}
```

After fetching the queue from APC and retrieving the top item in the priority queue, using `$this->extract()`, I don't get the item but the array that is created during serialization.

So, instead of a `PriorityQueueItem`, the base class I use for objects stored in the queue, I get an associative array with indices *data* and *priority* (similar to the array in the serialize function). To get the actual item I need to retrive the *data* part of the array instead of treating the returned item as an item, which is how it works when not storing the queue in APC and how I assumed it would work now as well.

Is this a feature of serialization of objects or am I approaching this in a wrong way?

**Update:** The issue here was that I had a separate function that did extra cruft besides the `extract()`. This function returned the item as an array, but as soon as I called `extract()` explicitly I got the item as expected. Are there certain precautions to take with public functions in objects that have been serialized?

Comment: Functions are not part of the serialization process. Serialization will only cover either your own serializable implementation or private, protected and public (non-static) members (not functions). If you want to inspect serialized data to look what's happening behind the scenes, checkout [`Serialized`](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized) it can display the data of serialized strings nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed/switched this probably:

In your code you are serializing the `$data` array, not "your object". I'm not entirely sure of this because I do not know what the `insert()` function is for.

But for the serialize in an object with the [`serializable` interface](http://php.net/class.serializable) you will get back what has been returned from `object::serialize()`.

As you serialize an array, you will get the serialized array back. PHP in the background is taking care that this was stored as your object.

Comment: The `insert()` in `serialize()` re-inserts the items in the queue, since the traversal of the queue in the preceding for-loop removes all items. As I added in my update to the initial question, I used a function that implicitly called `extract()` and returned what I thought was the item but turned out to be the array. When I call `extract()` explicitly I get the item as expected. Problem solved, but this limits what I wanted to do during extraction from the queue (but something I can live with, I guess).

Comment: Okay now I better understand your underlying problem. Iterating over the data will remove it. Doesn't that class allow you to access the queue's data without modifying it? I think there should be an object member you can just get the data from w/o removing it. Would be more straight forward and less error prone.